# Flutter: Audio Slider is not working properly in Chat

Tags: flutter, chat, record, flutter-provider, audio-player

I am working in a chat where i added voice message feature. I used `audioplayer` and `record` package for this, and it is working perfectly. But problem is let say i sent two audio when i play the first one audio is playing but my second message audio slider is also playing parallelly and its icon is in play it should be pause, however i print the audio url it is playing first audio. In short audio is playing only one, all audio slider are moving.

here is my UI code:

```
SizedBox(
      height: 100,
      child: ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          // physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemScrollController: itemScrollController,
          itemCount: chatModelList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return audioWidget(audioUrl:chatModelList[index].message);
                
          }),
    );
```

```
Widget audioWidget({String? audioUrl}){
SliderTheme(
                    data: const SliderThemeData(
                        trackHeight: 5,
                        thumbShape:
                            RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 5)),
                    child: Consumer<MyAudioProvider>(
                        builder: (_, myAudioModel, child) {
                      return Row(
                        children: [
                          GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                if (myAudioModel.audioState == "Completed") {
                                  setState(() {
                                    // iscompleted = true;
                                    myAudioModel.audioState == "Completed";
                                  });
                                } else {
                                }
                                myAudioModel.startAudio();
                                myAudioModel.audioState == "Playing"
                                    ? myAudioModel.pauseAudio()
                                    : myAudioModel.audioState == "Completed"
                                        ? myAudioModel.playAudio(url: audioUrl)
                                        : myAudioModel.playAudio(url: audioUrl);
                              },
                              child: Icon(
                                myAudioModel.audioState == "Playing"
                                    ? Icons.pause
                                    : Icons.play_arrow,
                                color: AppColors.blueColor,
                                size: 0.07.sw,
                              )),

                          SizedBox(
                            width: 0.01.sw,
                          ),
                          CustomText(
                            text: durationToString(myAudioModel.totalDuration),
                            fontColor: AppColors.greyBlackColor,
                            fontSize: 12,
                          ),

                          Expanded(
                            child: Slider(
                              value: myAudioModel.audioState == "Completed"
                                  ? 0.0
                                  : myAudioModel.position.inMilliseconds
                                      .toDouble(),
                              activeColor: AppColors.blueColor,
                              inactiveColor:
                                  AppColors.greyBlackColor.withOpacity(0.3),
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                myAudioModel.seekAudio(
                                    Duration(milliseconds: value.toInt()));
                              },
                              min: 0.0,
                              max: myAudioModel.totalDuration == null
                                  ? 20
                                  : myAudioModel.totalDuration.inMilliseconds
                                      .toDouble(),
                            ),
                          ),
                          CustomText(
                            text: durationToString(myAudioModel.position),
                            fontColor: AppColors.greyBlackColor,
                            fontSize: 12,
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    }),
                  ),
}
```

here is my ChatModel

```
class ChatModel{
  int? id;
  int? userId;
  String? name;
  String? image;
  String? message;
  String? time;
  String? msgType;
  bool? isReplyMessage;
  String? oldMessage;
  int? originalChatId;
  String? oldMessageType;
  ChatModel({this.id,this.name,this.originalChatId,this.oldMessageType, this.oldMessage, this.userId,this.image,this.message,this.time,this.msgType,this.isReplyMessage});
}
```

and here is audio provider where i am controlling audio functions

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyAudioProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Duration totalDuration = const Duration();
  Duration position = const Duration();
  String? audioState;
  int count = 0;

  MyAudioProvider() {
  }

  AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();

  startAudio() {
    audioPlayer.onDurationChanged.listen((updatedDuration) {
      totalDuration = updatedDuration;
      notifyListeners();
    });

    audioPlayer.onPositionChanged.listen((updatedPosition) {
      position = updatedPosition;
      notifyListeners();
    });

    audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((playerState) {
      // log("playerState  $playerState");
      if (playerState == PlayerState.stopped) {
        audioState = "Stopped";
      }
      if (playerState == PlayerState.playing) {
        audioState = "Playing";
      }
      if (playerState == PlayerState.paused) {
        audioState = "Paused";
      }
      if (playerState == PlayerState.completed) {
        audioState = "Completed";
        if (audioState == "Completed") {
          position = const Duration(
            days: 0,
            hours: 0,
            minutes: 0,
            seconds: 0,
            microseconds: 0,
            milliseconds: 0,
          );
        } else {
        }
      }
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  playAudio({String? url}) {
    log("playAudio called AUDIO URL IN MYADUIO   $url");
       audioPlayer.play(UrlSource(url.toString()));

    notifyListeners();
  
  }

  pauseAudio() {
    audioPlayer.pause();
  }

  stopAudio() {
    audioPlayer.stop();
  }

  seekAudio(Duration durationToSeek) {
    audioPlayer.seek(durationToSeek);
  }
}
```

kindly help how to fix this issue.